# rows are not being added to xlform using addRow: afterRow: method

Tags: objective-c, xlform

I am trying to dynamically add a new row to my XLForm if the value of another changes. I logged the value of the first row and everything is working fine, but the row is not being added. I've messed around with it for a few hours with no luck.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)rowDescriptor oldValue:(id)oldValue newValue:(id)newValue
{
    [super formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged:rowDescriptor oldValue:oldValue newValue:newValue];

    if ([rowDescriptor.tag isEqualToString:@"later"]){
      if ([[newValue valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(1)] == YES){
          NSLog(@"NEW VALUE %@", [newValue valueData]);
                                                 rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeDateTimeInline
        XLFormRowDescriptor *n = [XLFormRowDescriptor formRowDescriptorWithTag:@"time"
                                                                       rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeDateTimeInline
                                                                         title:@"Date and Time"];

        [self.formO addFormRow:n afterRow:rowDescriptor];
    }
    else if ([[newValue valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(0)] == NO){
        [self.form removeFormRowWithTag:@"time"];
        NSLog(@"NEW VALUE %@", [newValue valueData]);

    }
}
}
```

Here is the framework
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/XLForm/2.1.0/Protocols/XLFormDescriptorCell.html

Any suggestions would be greatly suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show the "time" row only if the "later" row has a value of 1, right?
This problem can be solved more easily in version 3.0 of XLForm. In that version you have a hidden property for each row so it should work if you set it like this when you define your form:

```
row = [XLFormRowDescriptor formRowDescriptorWithTag:@"time" rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeDateTimeInline title:@"Date and time"];
row.hidden = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$later != 1",];
```

You should define this row upfront and you don't have to add and remove it yourself.